# In python (django) how can I stop access to a global dictionary data structure when it's being updated?

Tags: python, django

In django when updating a global dictionary data structure I want to lock access to it by different request. I am planning to have a wrapper function to update and access and synchronize it. Coming from Java background! Any pointers?

Comment: use the global declaration only, if there is no other way; it's usually a sign for a refactoring possiblity and i saw its usage in production code at most once.

Comment: What do you mean by a "global dictionary"?  How will this work when you site expands and requires multiple concurrent Django daemons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to lock an object in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698950/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-lock-an-object-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the LockableDict example somewhat, to make it a little more robust you can use the real Lock:

```
class LockableDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from threading import Lock
        self.lock = Lock()
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def locked(self):
        return self.lock.locked()

    def lock(self):
        self.lock.acquire()

    def unlock(self):
        self.lock.release()

# and then
my_dict = LockableDict({1:2, 3:4})
my_dict.lock()
# do modifications
my_dict.unlock()
```

Comment: Thanks, just that the lock name is common for the function and the variable! rest worked great

Comment: yes sorry about that, better call the attribute __lock to make it ptivate

Answer (score 1):

One fun option is to create a Lockable DIctionary class that will lock itself based on teh exection frame of the caller.   :-)

Python introspection allows this - and depending on you r needs, this might fit - 
(you would have to catch the exception raised in the places you want to use the valu, though -- 
I don' t  use Django, so I don't know if the rewquests use threads -- if so, (and not asynchronous response over a single thread for all requests), you can replace the Exception raised for a while - sleep - retry loop.

```
from inspect import stack

class DictLocked(Exception):
    pass

class LockableDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.locked = False
        self.locker = None
    def start_update(self):
        print stack()
        self.locked = True
        #Holds the code frame responsible for locking
        self.locker = stack()[1][0]
    def finish_update(self):
        self.locked = False

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print stack()
        if self.locked:
            if stack()[1][0] != self.locker:
                raise DictLocked("Dictionary locked")
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if self.locked:
            if stack()[1][0] != self.locker:
                raise DictLocked("Dictionary locked")
        return dict.__setitem__(self, item, value)
```