# Run Python HTTPServer in Background and Continue Script Execution

Tags: python, python-multithreading, basehttpserver, python-daemon

I am trying to figure out how to run my overloaded customized BaseHTTPServer instance in the background after running the "".serve_forever() method.

Normally when you run the method execution will hang until you execute a keyboard interrupt, but I would like it to serve requests in the background while continuing script execution.  Please help!

Answer (score 16):

You can start the server in a different thread: https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#thread.start_new_thread

So something like:

```py
import _thread as thread

def start_server():
    # Setup stuff here...
    server.serve_forever()
    
# start the server in a background thread
thread.start_new_thread(start_server, ())
    
print('The server is running but my script is still executing!')
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do some long-term animation using async and thought I'd have to rewrite server to use aiohttp (https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v0.12.0/web.html), but Olivers technique of using seperate thread saved me all that pain. My code looks like this, where MyHTTPServer is simply my custom sublass of HTTPServer

```
import threading
import asyncio
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socketserver
import io
import threading

async def tick_async(server):        
    while True:
        server.animate_something()
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

def start_server():
    httpd.serve_forever()
    
try:
    print('Server listening on port 8082...')

    httpd = MyHTTPServer(('', 8082), MyHttpHandler)
    asyncio.ensure_future(tick_async(httpd))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
    t.start()
    loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using `concurrent.futures` :

```py
import concurrent.futures
import http.server

def run_http_server():
    port = 8080
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()

def run_parallel_http_server():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    executor.submit(run_http_server)
    executor.shutdown(wait=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_parallel_http_server()
    # do something else..
```